# Modal for multiple images on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, bootstrap-modal

***Repeat Post** 
I have searched around and found a potential answer to **adding a modal to one page for multiple images**. This solution I found is giving me my modal but when the modal pops up the image is not showing and the console showing the "img src" is "(unknown)".

The solution I found:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
            $(".img-responsive").attr("src", image);
        });
});
```

```html
<img id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="image" src="/images/hieroglyphics/9.jpg">



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="img-responsive" src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that your code seems to work correctly.
here is a fiddle with your code.
https://jsfiddle.net/jammer99/y0w1t95u/

Are you sure there isn't anything else opening the modal?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
        $(".img-responsive").attr("src", image);
    });
});
```

can you paste a screenshot of your console? to check if there are any other errors?

Comment: No other errors are being thrown. Am I correct that this javascript is being ran through JQuery or is that wrong?

Comment: I actually just added the Bootstrap css CDN and am now getting thrown this error...

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {         bootstrap.min.css:5"

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3.3.7? can you update the fiddle with your issue?

Comment: First time using JSFiddle. I believe I updated to what mine looks like. Thank you for your help Rohit! https://jsfiddle.net/y0w1t95u/2/

Comment: The fiddle is working. Please check your code or paste a screenshot of your console window,

Comment: This might sound terrible, but I do not see how to post a picture on the comments.

Comment: just upload it on any image sharing site and paste the link (ex. imgur)